# What can be done about a question marked as an exact duplicate of another which is not remotely the same, when another question is an exact original?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, disputed-flags

I recently flagged [How do I pass a variable into pattern of function preg_match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070249/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-into-pattern-of-function-preg-match) (Q1) as a duplicate of [How do I use a variable pattern with preg_match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386748/how-do-i-use-a-variable-pattern-with-preg-match) (Q2) since Q1 is asking **exactly** the same question as Q2.

At approximately the same time, another user flagged Q1 as a duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) (Q3) which is an extremely different question.

Q3's answers address part of the problem faced by the OP of Q1, but from an oblique perspective.

Q2's answers address **exactly** the problem faced by the OP of Q1, covering the relevant parts addressed by the answers of Q3 but **in context**, and the more specific issues Q3 doesn't touch.

My flag has been marked as *"disputed"* and Q1 has been marked as an exact duplicate of Q3.

- Is it possible to reflag Q1 as being a duplicate of Q2, or dispute the marking of it as a duplicate of Q3?

Note: I searched Meta before posting and have read several suggested/similar questions and their answers, but I'm not so interested in my flagging history, or if the *"disputed"* flag should or could be changed in the event of a review in *my favor*; I am only concerned that semantically, the current connection between Q1 and Q3 in nonsense.

Comment: I pinged the user who dupe hammered that question to chime in here.

Comment: It was hammered correctly. Q2 does nothing to highlight what the actual problem was in Q1's attempt, while Q3 does so directly.

Comment: Assuming that what @PaulCrovella says is true, and from the looks of it it is true, should Q2 then also be dupe-linked to Q3 given that its basically the same question as Q1?

Comment: @Gimby No, Q2 does not have the same problem that Q1 does. The questions might have the same theme but their underlying problems are completely different - Q2 was missing appropriate regex delimiters while Q1  used incorrect quotes leading to the variable not being interpolated. Q2's issue is closely tied to regex handling, while Q1's has to do with basic string handling in PHP.

Comment: The second-most upvoted answer on Q2 (_"u can use variable by putting it between []"_) is actually quite wrong, incidentally.

Comment: Q3 is not about the use of `preg_match()` and none of its answers mention `preg_match()`. Q2 is asking the exact same question as Q1 and its accepted answer provides a direct and context relevant solution. Telling readers of Q1 that _"This question already has an answer here: Q3"_ is telling them to figure out the relevance themselves, since there's no obvious connection if they don't already know why Q3 is relevant, and its answers (quite understandably) don't provide info about the unique delimitation required in `preg_match()`.

Comment: @FredGandt  You need to look past the title of the questions to the actual issues. It's not much to ask people to read Q3 and figure out how it applies to their question (in fact a *large* number of questions get closed against it doing just that) - it's a pretty obvious hint that they've misunderstood which quotes to use. It doesn't matter that Q3 doesn't talk about regex delimiters - Q1 already has them, it's not the problem at hand.